# Why is a label with JPG Picture on a Userfom (Excel) Transparent (as if PNG/GiF)?

Tags: excel

I have a Userform with Picture background.
Place a Label control on it, with Backstyle set to transparent.
in Picture (of the label), i chose a JPG Picture (with whithe background or any mono-color background.

and it's funny, but the mono-color background becomes transparent, wich is a cool way doing transparency for pictures on a userform without using any code.

Is this a normal behaviour ? can you guys replicate it ? (excel 2013 64bit)

Wanted to share this info for people who are not confortable with programming in VBA, and still want some transparency/Opacity.

remember: it works only with a **Label**, and not with a Image control !
[image]

on the left label, on the right, the same JPG Picture on a Image control (with backstyle set also transparent).

EDIT : after some testing around, i found it works with a button control too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `BackStyle` is set to `fmBackStyleTransparent` the colour of the **bottom left** pixel is taken to be the background colour and used to apply transparency to the `Picture` image.

Comment: "Note

BackStyle does not affect the transparency of bitmaps. You must use a picture editor such as Paintbrush to make a bitmap transparent. Not all controls support transparent bitmaps." ,  from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251737.aspx